# ERROR -android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Im trying to implement a score functionality in my App but I always get that same error that is in the main title, my error is in the following button

```
     em=bundle.getString("EMAIL");
    SQL usdbh =new SQL (this, "DBUsuarios", null, 1);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
             Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 FROM Usuarios WHERE Email='"+em+"' ", null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                    p1= c.getInt(0);

                      p2= c.getInt(1);

                      p3= c.getInt(2);

                     p4= c.getInt(3);

                     p5= c.getInt(4);

                     if(n7>p1){
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p1="+n7+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p2="+p1+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p3="+p2+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p4="+p3+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p5="+p4+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");

                     }
                     if(n7>p2&&n7<p1){
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p2="+n7+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p3="+p2+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p4="+p3+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p5="+p4+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");

                     }
                     if(n7>p3&&n7<p2){

                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p3="+n7+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p4="+p3+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p5="+p4+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");

                     }
                     if(n7>p4&&n7<p3){


                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p4="+n7+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");
                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p5="+p4+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");

                     }
                     if(n7>p5&&n7<p4){


                      db.execSQL("UPDATE Usuarios SET p5="+n7+" WHERE Email='"+em+"' ");

                     }

             c.close();
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Cinco.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("PUNT", n7);
                    intent2.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });
```

I did the same cursor the same at the MainActivity class with no errors but it just putted the Scores in textViews it didnt insert values into the tables

The scores are inserted correctly but I always get" Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped." =(
Any ideas?
PD= this is my first question so be pattient if I did something wrong =)

Comment: It's clearly saying that you're accessing 0th position in your array where it has no element in it that's what `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` is. Look into your stack trace on which line it's happening or post your stack trace here then alter you logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First off, always post the entire stack trace.

Secondly, you tried to access a cursor with no results.  This caused you to crash.  Check the return value of moveToFirst.  If it returns false, you have no results and need to not access it.

Additionally, NEVER write an SQL query with concatenation to make the WHERE clause.  Always use bind variables.  Using concatenation causes you to risk SQL injection and it prevents the db from optimizing for the generalized query.

Comment: Hey I checked the return value of the c.moveToFirst this way if(c.moveToFirst)´and then the insert commands. It does the actions requested by those commands so the return value must be true, any idea?, I keep getting the same error =(